# Div with downward triangle and uniform background image

Tags: html, css, scroll, background-image

I'm not sure if this is even possible. But I am trying to make something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hayleycnelson/dhran86o/8/

```css
* { margin: 0; padding:0;}

.box 
{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 70vh;
padding: 0px;
background: url(https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_face_glasses_thick_65455_1920x1080.jpg);
background-size: 100%;
filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}

.box:before 
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 70vh; /* must match width of div */
left: 48vw;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 26px 26px 0;
border-color: lightblue transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> </div>
```

but with a background image that spans throughout the div **and** the downward triangle. But I would like the background image to be static (i.e. when you scroll down it stays there but everything else moves). Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342956/same-linear-gradient-background-in-after-as-in-div/51343025#51343025 .. replace gradient with your background

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much